# Google Sign In not recognizing sign in Callback function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, google-signin

I am building a small Angular app and I am using Google Sign-In. I am just using the sample code from the tutorial Google gives.

```
              <span class="g-signin"
                data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
                data-clientid="blah"
                data-redirecturi="postmessage"
                data-accesstype="offline"
                data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                data-callback="signInCallback">
              </span>
```

That's the element that makes the button to sign in, and I run this code to start

```
(function () {
  var po = document.createElement('script');
  po.type = 'text/javascript';
  po.async = true;
  po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=start';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
```

, all of which are copied from Google. I then have this method in my controller,

```
.controller('splashController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
        $scope.googleLogin() = function(){
                $scope.googleAuthResult = $window.googleAuthResult;
                console.log($scope.googleAuthResult);
        };


        window.signInCallback = function(authResult){
                console.log("happy");
        };
}])
```

But the problem is that after the google+ script is run, it is looking around outside of Angular World for this signInCallback function, which I want to keep in Angular because I want to send the token off via angular and not like jQuery. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume this is because of not injecting the right service or letting Angular know about $window or something but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you move your (function() into the controller, or into a .run() module? That might help.

Comment: i tried putting the anon function into a run module but it doesn't change the fact that the google+ script wants to see a function not in Angular...although i do like the run() a bit better because it's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `gapi.auth.authorize` method.  It invokes the same functionality as the button, but explicitly via Javascript, and it also allows you to pass in a callback method on the scope of your controller/service/whatever.  Here's my login function:

```
var authParams =                    // Define a params object for gapi.auth.authorize
{
    client_id       : '****-****.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope           : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    immediate       : false,
    cookiepolicy    : 'single_host_origin'
};

/**
 * Authenticates the user and authorizes the local browser's JS GAPI Client, returns an object
 * with the GAPI Client's login token or false if it's not yet available, and the deferred 
 * object whose promise will be resolved when the JS GAPI Client authenticates.
 *
 * @param hard      If {{ hard }} is truthy, force the GAPI Client to reauthenticate the user
 *                  and reauthorize the client.  Ensures the client is logged in and the session
 *                  stays active even if it is disrupted external to the application.
 */
this.login = function(hard)
{
    // @TODO:   Consolidate into (!hard && (token || pending) if token can be guaranteed falsey
    //          while pending otherwise ret.logged is unreliable.  
    //          Where's a logical XOR when you need one?
    //////////////////////////
    // If a login is pending and we're not forcing a hard reauth, return the deferred object
    // promising the authorization response and 'logged':false
    if (pending && !hard) return { logged : false, deferred : deferred };

    // If the token is already set and we're not forcing a hard reauth, resolve the deferred
    // promise immediately and return it along with 'logged':token
    if (token && !hard)
    {
        deferred.resolve(token); // Resolve the promise immediately, no login response to wait for
        return { logged : token, deferred : deferred };
    }
    /////////////////////////

    deferred = $q.defer();  // We need to wait for gapi.auth.authorize to respond, reinit the promise
    pending = true;         // Don't restart the process on future calls if an authorization is pending
    gapi.auth.authorize(authParams,this.handleAuthResult);  // Authorize the client, then run the callback

    // Not logged in, return the deferred object
    return { logged : false, deferred : deferred};
}
```

All contained in a service.

Comment: For more up-to-date info you can go here - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

And the API reference for JS Client Library is here - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs